# Text meaning in Response type for ASP.NET after Ajax action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Example of HTTP Response after the Ajax action:

```
1|#||4|5728|updatePanel|ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_updatePanel1|
                <div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_98e2461c-a8c0-4a65-9d98-2ee4b8c0b1cd" class="multiple-choice-check-box-horiz clearfix fieldset">
<div class="question-box">
    <div class="question-area">
        <div class="question-container">
            <div class="question">
                <span class="question-text">Choice - Multiple Answers (Horizontal) No question test</span>
            </div><div class="choices clearfix">
                <ul id='chkMC' class='multiselect-checkboxes horizontal left clearfix'><li><span class="radio-btn"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_CheckboxChoices0-842352753" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$CheckboxChoices0-842352753" onclick="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$CheckboxChoices0-842352753\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" /></span><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl01_CheckboxChoices0-842352753">1</label></li></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question what does the meaning of first few characters in the response i.e. **1|#||4|**. Is this some kind of token?

Comment: There is a whole bunch of information it sends back about what to change, how to change it, etc. I guess it's probably related to that. There is probably some form of request/response ordering going on tho that I can't confirm. Other than that never bothered. Try not to use updatepanels mate :)

Comment: Standard format is `contentLength|controlType|controlID|content|`, but I'm not sure what is `1|#||4`

Comment: 1|#||4 got appended in .NET 4.0 only. Can someone tell us what does this means? We used to pull the response length (5728 in this case) and modify the response html on the fly and then flush the buffer. But now with the introduction of this special token or string, our logic apparently got failed.. Now we were thinking what does this signify ? so we can alter the response filter modification safely.